# react rerendering form causes focus/blur issue on state change

Tags: forms, reactjs, focus, blur

I have a form in a react component that has two change handlers, one for my two draftjs textareas, and one for my other text inputs:

```
onChangeEditor = (editorStateKey) => (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ [editorStateKey]: editorState });
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

In my render method I have two views that I switch between depending on which view mode I am in, read or edit:

```
render () {

    const Editable = () => (
        <div className="editor">
            <form className="editor-inner">
                <h3>Redigerar: Anbudsbrev</h3>
                <h4>Rubrik</h4>
                <input type="text" key="text01" name="title" defaultValue={this.state.title} onBlur={this.handleInputChange} />
                <h4>Text 1</h4>
                <RichEditor editorState={this.state.editorState1} onChange={this.onChangeEditor('editorState1')} name="text01"/>
                <h4>Citat</h4>
                <input type="text" key="text02" name="quote01" defaultValue={this.state.quote01} onBlur={this.handleInputChange} />
                <h4>Text 2</h4>
                <RichEditor editorState={this.state.editorState2} onChange={this.onChangeEditor('editorState2')} name="text02" />
                <EditorFooter {...this.props} submitForm={this.saveForm} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );

    const Readable = () => (
        <div>
            <h1 className="header66">{this.state.title}</h1>
            <div className="text66">{this.state.text01}</div>
            <div className="quote100">{this.state.quote01}</div>
            <div className="text66">{this.state.text02}</div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            { this.props.isInEditMode ? <Editable /> : <Readable /> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I switch between inputs in my browser I have to click twice in order to get the focus on the right input.

I suspect that this is because a change is triggered on the "blur" event of each input, causing the form to rerender because state is changed. And when the form rerenders, it goes through the `{ this.props.isInEditMode ? <Editable /> : <Readable /> }` which causes the input to lose focus.

The problem is that I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

It turns out that it was not a good idea to place the `Editable` and `Readable` inside of my component as I did. Instead I moved them out to their own components, and it works properly now.

```
class Editable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="editor">
                <form className="editor-inner">
                    <h3>Redigerar: Anbudsbrev</h3>
                    <h4>Rubrik</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="title" defaultValue={this.props.title} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
                    <h4>Text 1</h4>
                    <RichEditor editorState={this.props.editorState1} onChange={this.props.onChangeEditor('editorState1')} name="text01" />
                    <h4>Citat</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="quote01" defaultValue={this.props.quote01} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
                    <h4>Text 2</h4>
                    <RichEditor editorState={this.props.editorState2} onChange={this.props.onChangeEditor('editorState2')} name="text02" />
                    <EditorFooter {...this.props} submitForm={this.props.saveForm} />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class Readable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="header66">{this.props.title}</h1>
                <div className="text66">{this.props.text01}</div>
                <div className="quote100">{this.props.quote01}</div>
                <div className="text66">{this.props.text02}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```